# Pdf to svg is not perfect

Tags: svg, imagemagick, ghostscript, imagemagick-convert, inkscape

I have tried nearly every library to convert pdf to svg, Following are the results of them

1. gs or ghostscript and imagemagick: The size gets multiplied by 100
2. pdf2svg and inkscape: The image on the top of the pdf is not at all accurate here are the links to the pdf and the svg.

PDF: https://drive.google.com/open?id=0BxyQR1owWa_pcnhhSk5wQWJGMVk
SVG: https://drive.google.com/open?id=0BxyQR1owWa_pVnhoLVlob1U2d1k

Please suggest me if I am missing something that needs to be done.

Comment: This guy talks about his experience when using various library to do this [About PDF to SVG converters](https://gist.github.com/douglasmiranda/9c19f23c4570a7b7e02137791880ab43 "About PDF to SVG converters")

Answer (score 2):

The Ghostscript SVG output device is seriously deprecated and no longer supported (or indeed built into the standard Ghostscript binary).

In any event, you need to be aware that PDF is a very rich graphics model, and it is simply not possible to reproduce every possible nuance of a PDF using the SVG graphics model, in particular fonts are a problem, but so is almost any kind of transparency. When that occurs Ghostscript will render the PDF to an image, and insert that into an SVG file. Almost certainly that's why you are seeing the SVG file being considerably larger than the PDF file. You should be able to use the -r switch to control the resolution of the rendering, allowing you to trade off quality for size.

Even if the whole file isn't converted to a bitmap, its possible that large portions of it are, or that the bitmap compression in SVG is less good than for PDF (or GS isn't taking advantage of all the possibilities). FWIW the PDF file uncompressed runs to > 4MB.

Comment: Can we use - r on svg also?  I thought it was only for pdf operations.

Comment: I tried it using the -r option given a value of 10 it returns a svg of 51 MB.

Comment: -r is used whenever Ghostscript needs to render content, it works (obviously) for all rendering devices such as TIFF or PNG. But it is also used when high level vector devices need to render something, they will use the specified resolution, or the default (for pdfwrite that is 720 dpi). I can't say why the SVG device is producing a large file, that device is unsupported.

Comment: So is there any any other approach that you can suggest to do so beacuse I've tried with Pdf, html and Png, these all not suited one way or the other for the Android devices, The only method that I found working is a SVG.I've tried IDR library to convert PDF to SVG, It works perfect but it is a paid library.

Comment: I'd just stick with PDF, there are plenty of PDF readers on Android

Comment: Yes, but they are extremely slow when it comes to rendering and zooming.

Comment: Maybe you should look into a different viewer then.

Comment: I have tried many free as well as paid libraries, It is not as smooth as in IOS, so we tried the SVG rendering and it is good in android but on the server we are not able to convert it to SVG.